# What is this image?

Tags: dna, microscopy

[image]

What I understand is- I think this is picture of DNA. But why is it in this conformation ? What types of cells have this type of DNA ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a [Holliday junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holliday_junction). It forms during recombination.

Comment: Well, I am curoius - how did you find this out ?!

Comment: Just guessed it.. It resembled the textbook diagram of Holliday junction. :)

Comment: This is a pretty well known image and you definitely come across it, when you study in this direction.